# python - Changing TMPDIR still caused error28: No space left on device

Tags: python

I have been trying to install Bokeh to my conda virtual environment when i got this error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

When i used the command `df -h` to show the system's memory, it shows:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       6.9G  6.4G   88M  99% /
devtmpfs        211M     0  211M   0% /dev
tmpfs           216M     0  216M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           216M  3.2M  213M   2% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           216M     0  216M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p3  7.3G 1009M  5.9G  15% /media/sd
/dev/mmcblk0p6  253M   52M  201M  21% /boot
tmpfs            44M     0   44M   0% /run/user/1000
```

So I have tried to set the directory TMPDIR by using `$export TMPDIR=/media/sd`, which has more memory but the error is still there.

Can i know what is causing the problem?

Comment: Maybe the installer is not using the `TMPDIR` variable?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I use pip to install the module so i think it should respect the  TMPDIR